# Gulp task - unable to set variable value

Tags: gulp, gulp-header

I'm using `git-rev`,`gulp-header` and `run-sequence` and trying to add some info - as well as - git commit number automatically to app.js file during building process.

here's the code I have so far:

```
var runSequence = require('gulp-run-sequence');
var git = require('git-rev');
var header = require('gulp-header');
var pkg = require('./info.json');

var paths = {addHeader: ['./www/js/app.js'], ...}

var commit, timestamp;
function getGitInfo() {
    git.short(function (str) {
        commit = str;
        console.log(str);
    });
};

var banner = ['"commit":"' + commit + '",',
    '"timestamp":"' + timestamp + '",',
    '"appVersion":"<%= pkg.appVersion %>",',
    '"appReleaseDate":"<%= pkg.appReleaseDate %>"',
    '};\n',
    ''].join('\n');

gulp.task('get-git-info', getGitInfo());
gulp.task('add-header', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.addHeader)
        .pipe(header(banner, {pkg: pkg}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www-dev/js/'))
});

gulp.task('build', function (){
  runSequence('get-git-info','add-header');
})
```

the console result is right, I have the commit number, but in app.js all I get is undefined:

```
aboutPage={
"appVersion":"5.0.0",
"appReleaseDate":"10/02/2016",
"commit":"undefined",
"timestamp":"undefined"
};
```

I am talking about commit, and NOT timestamp. I'm going to worry about timestamp later.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your Gulpfile:

1. Your `banner` variable is initialized *before* any of your tasks are even defined, let alone have been executed. That means that `commit` is still `undefined` when you initialize `banner`.
2. `gulp.task` expects a function as the task body. However the task body for `get-git-info` in your Gulpfile is `getGitInfo()`. That means you *execute* the `getGitInfo` function and assign the *return value of that function call* as the task body of `get-git-info`. Which in your case is `undefined`.
3. Even if you had assigned the `getGitInfo` function itself as the task body (instead of its return value), it still wouldn't work because `git.short()` is asynchronous. That means that `get-git-info` returns and `add-header` is run *before* your callback function to `git.short()` is called with the commit-id.

Here's a solution that addresses all three of these problems:

```
function banner() {
    return [
        '"commit":"' + commit + '",',
        '"timestamp":"' + timestamp + '",',
        '"appVersion":"<%= pkg.appVersion %>",',
        '"appReleaseDate":"<%= pkg.appReleaseDate %>"',
        '};\n',
        ''
    ].join('\n');
}

gulp.task('get-git-info', function(done) {
    git.short(function (str) {
        commit = str;
        console.log(str);
        done();
    });
});

gulp.task('add-header', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.addHeader)
        .pipe(header(banner(), {pkg: pkg}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www-dev/js/'))
});
```

1. `banner` is now a function so the `commit` variable isn't accessed until it has been initialized.
2. `getGitInfo` is gone. Instead an anonymous function is used as the task body for `get-git-info`, so it's dead obvious that we are in fact assigning a function here.
3. The anonymous function accepts a callback `done` which is called once the commit-id is available. This signals to gulp that `get-git-info` is finished and that `runSequence` can proceed with the `add-header` task.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both for the explanation and the example!